# While training throws up a huge compile time error which says TLS init function undefined reference to arma::mt19937_64_instance

Tags: c++, neural-network, c++20, undefined-reference, mlpack

The undefined reference is generally a linker error. I feel like the error is because of my compilation of mlpack rather than code but I do not know how to track it down or if my assumption is correct. Or if it is a bug and there is a work around.

I have written the code using this as reference - [mlpack documentation](https://www.mlpack.org/doc/stable/doxygen/anntutorial.html#model_api_anntut)

-Forgive my includes, I copied them from another file directly-

The error comes up only due to the Train statement, everything else worked fine. I used armadillo in other places and was working fine with complex data and matrix operations like eigen values generation, transpose of vectors, vector operations etc. So, I know that the error probably isn't in armadillo.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <execution>

#include <mlpack/prereqs.hpp>
#include <mlpack/core.hpp>
#include <mlpack/core/data/split_data.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/ann/layer/layer.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/ann/ffn.hpp>


namespace fs = std::filesystem;

constexpr auto PI = 3.14159265f;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::complex_literals;
using namespace mlpack;
using namespace mlpack::ann;

int main() {
    arma::mat trainData;
    trainData = {
        {1.0,11.0,21.0,31.0},
        {2.0,12.0,22.0,32.0},
        {3.0,13.0,23.0,33.0},
        {4.0,14.0,24.0,34.0},
        {6.0,16.0,26.0,36.0},
        {7.0,17.0,27.0,37.0},
        {8.0,18.0,28.0,38.0},
        {9.0,19.0,29.0,39.0}
    };
    arma::mat trainLabel;
    trainLabel = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0} ;

    trainData.print();
    trainLabel.print();

    FFN<> model;
    model.Add<Linear<> >(trainData.n_rows, 12);
    model.Add<SigmoidLayer<> >();
    model.Add<Linear<> >(12, 3);
    model.Add<LogSoftMax<> >();

    model.Train(trainData, trainLabel);

}
```

I run the code using the below command

```
g++ -O3 minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp -Iarmadillo/include -Imlpack/include/ -Iboost/include -Larmadillo/lib -Lblas/lib/ -Lboost/lib -Llapack/ -Lmlpack/lib -Lopenblas/lib -Iopenblas/include -fopenmp -larmadillo -lmlpack -std=c++2a -w -o minCode.o
```

I tried splitting the g++ command into -c and compile the object file after that with linker. It failed at the linker part. The compile part just gives me depreceated-declarations warning from boost library.

and this is the error I get -

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNWv7em.o: in function `arma::arma_rng::randn<double>::fill(double*, unsigned long long)':
minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy[_ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy]+0x56): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy[_ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy]+0x71): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy[_ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy]+0x1e0): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy[_ZN4arma8arma_rng5randnIdE4fillEPdy]+0x1e7): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNWv7em.o: in function `void mlpack::math::ShuffleData<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double>&, std::enable_if<!arma::is_SpMat<arma::Mat<double> >::value, void>::type const*, std::enable_if<!arma::is_Cube<arma::Mat<double> >::value, void>::type const*)':
minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack4math11ShuffleDataIN4arma3MatIdEES4_EEvRKT_RKT0_RS5_RS8_PKNSt9enable_ifIXntsrNS2_8is_SpMatIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeEPKNSD_IXntsrNS2_7is_CubeIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeE[_ZN6mlpack4math11ShuffleDataIN4arma3MatIdEES4_EEvRKT_RKT0_RS5_RS8_PKNSt9enable_ifIXntsrNS2_8is_SpMatIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeEPKNSD_IXntsrNS2_7is_CubeIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeE]+0x31b): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack4math11ShuffleDataIN4arma3MatIdEES4_EEvRKT_RKT0_RS5_RS8_PKNSt9enable_ifIXntsrNS2_8is_SpMatIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeEPKNSD_IXntsrNS2_7is_CubeIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeE[_ZN6mlpack4math11ShuffleDataIN4arma3MatIdEES4_EEvRKT_RKT0_RS5_RS8_PKNSt9enable_ifIXntsrNS2_8is_SpMatIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeEPKNSD_IXntsrNS2_7is_CubeIS5_EE5valueEvE4typeE]+0x322): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNWv7em.o: in function `_ZN6mlpack3ann21NetworkInitializationINS0_20RandomInitializationEJEE10InitializeIdEEvRKSt6vectorIN5boost7variantIPNS0_18AdaptiveMaxPoolingIN4arma3MatIdEESB_EEJPNS0_19AdaptiveMeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_3AddISB_SB_EEPNS0_8AddMergeISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_12AlphaDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_17AtrousConvolutionINS0_16NaiveConvolutionINS0_16ValidConvolutionEEENSR_INS0_15FullConvolutionEEEST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_9BaseLayerINS0_16LogisticFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16IdentityFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_12TanhFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16SoftplusFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_17RectifierFunctionESB_SB_EEPNS0_9BatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_21BilinearInterpolationISB_SB_EEPNS0_4CELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6ConcatISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_11ConcatenateISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ConcatPerformanceINS0_21NegativeLogLikelihoodISB_SB_EESB_SB_EEPNS0_8ConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_11ConvolutionIST_SV_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_5CReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_11DropConnectISB_SB_EEPNS0_7DropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_3ELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8FastLSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_12FlexibleReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_3GRUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8HardTanHISB_SB_EEPNS0_4JoinISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LayerNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LeakyReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LinearISB_SB_NS0_13NoRegularizerEEEPNS0_12LinearNoBiasISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_10LogSoftMaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LookupISB_SB_EEPNS0_4LSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_10MaxPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_11MeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_23MiniBatchDiscriminationISB_SB_EEPNS0_16MultiplyConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_13MultiplyMergeISB_SB_JEEEPS1V_PNS0_11NoisyLinearISB_SB_EEPNS0_7PaddingISB_SB_EEPNS0_5PReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_7SoftmaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_14SpatialDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_21TransposedConvolutionIST_ST_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_10WeightNormISB_SB_JEEENS7_IPNS0_8Linear3DISB_SB_S32_EEJPNS0_7GlimpseISB_SB_EEPNS0_7HighwayISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18MultiheadAttentionISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_9RecurrentISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18RecurrentAttentionISB_SB_EEPNS0_15ReinforceNormalISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ReparametrizationISB_SB_EEPNS0_6SelectISB_SB_EEPNS0_10SequentialISB_SB_Lb0EJEEEPNS59_ISB_SB_Lb1EJEEEPNS0_7SubviewISB_SB_EEPNS0_13VRClassRewardISB_SB_EEPNS0_16VirtualBatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_3RBFISB_SB_NS0_16GaussianFunctionEEEPNSY_IS5O_SB_SB_EEPNS0_18PositionalEncodingISB_SB_EEEEEEEESaIS5X_EERNSA_IT_EEm':
minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann21NetworkInitializationINS0_20RandomInitializationEJEE10InitializeIdEEvRKSt6vectorIN5boost7variantIPNS0_18AdaptiveMaxPoolingIN4arma3MatIdEESB_EEJPNS0_19AdaptiveMeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_3AddISB_SB_EEPNS0_8AddMergeISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_12AlphaDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_17AtrousConvolutionINS0_16NaiveConvolutionINS0_16ValidConvolutionEEENSR_INS0_15FullConvolutionEEEST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_9BaseLayerINS0_16LogisticFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16IdentityFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_12TanhFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16SoftplusFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_17RectifierFunctionESB_SB_EEPNS0_9BatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_21BilinearInterpolationISB_SB_EEPNS0_4CELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6ConcatISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_11ConcatenateISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ConcatPerformanceINS0_21NegativeLogLikelihoodISB_SB_EESB_SB_EEPNS0_8ConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_11ConvolutionIST_SV_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_5CReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_11DropConnectISB_SB_EEPNS0_7DropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_3ELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8FastLSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_12FlexibleReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_3GRUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8HardTanHISB_SB_EEPNS0_4JoinISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LayerNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LeakyReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LinearISB_SB_NS0_13NoRegularizerEEEPNS0_12LinearNoBiasISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_10LogSoftMaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LookupISB_SB_EEPNS0_4LSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_10MaxPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_11MeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_23MiniBatchDiscriminationISB_SB_EEPNS0_16MultiplyConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_13MultiplyMergeISB_SB_JEEEPS1V_PNS0_11NoisyLinearISB_SB_EEPNS0_7PaddingISB_SB_EEPNS0_5PReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_7SoftmaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_14SpatialDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_21TransposedConvolutionIST_ST_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_10WeightNormISB_SB_JEEENS7_IPNS0_8Linear3DISB_SB_S32_EEJPNS0_7GlimpseISB_SB_EEPNS0_7HighwayISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18MultiheadAttentionISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_9RecurrentISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18RecurrentAttentionISB_SB_EEPNS0_15ReinforceNormalISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ReparametrizationISB_SB_EEPNS0_6SelectISB_SB_EEPNS0_10SequentialISB_SB_Lb0EJEEEPNS59_ISB_SB_Lb1EJEEEPNS0_7SubviewISB_SB_EEPNS0_13VRClassRewardISB_SB_EEPNS0_16VirtualBatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_3RBFISB_SB_NS0_16GaussianFunctionEEEPNSY_IS5O_SB_SB_EEPNS0_18PositionalEncodingISB_SB_EEEEEEEESaIS5X_EERNSA_IT_EEm[_ZN6mlpack3ann21NetworkInitializationINS0_20RandomInitializationEJEE10InitializeIdEEvRKSt6vectorIN5boost7variantIPNS0_18AdaptiveMaxPoolingIN4arma3MatIdEESB_EEJPNS0_19AdaptiveMeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_3AddISB_SB_EEPNS0_8AddMergeISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_12AlphaDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_17AtrousConvolutionINS0_16NaiveConvolutionINS0_16ValidConvolutionEEENSR_INS0_15FullConvolutionEEEST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_9BaseLayerINS0_16LogisticFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16IdentityFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_12TanhFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16SoftplusFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_17RectifierFunctionESB_SB_EEPNS0_9BatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_21BilinearInterpolationISB_SB_EEPNS0_4CELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6ConcatISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_11ConcatenateISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ConcatPerformanceINS0_21NegativeLogLikelihoodISB_SB_EESB_SB_EEPNS0_8ConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_11ConvolutionIST_SV_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_5CReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_11DropConnectISB_SB_EEPNS0_7DropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_3ELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8FastLSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_12FlexibleReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_3GRUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8HardTanHISB_SB_EEPNS0_4JoinISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LayerNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LeakyReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LinearISB_SB_NS0_13NoRegularizerEEEPNS0_12LinearNoBiasISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_10LogSoftMaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LookupISB_SB_EEPNS0_4LSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_10MaxPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_11MeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_23MiniBatchDiscriminationISB_SB_EEPNS0_16MultiplyConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_13MultiplyMergeISB_SB_JEEEPS1V_PNS0_11NoisyLinearISB_SB_EEPNS0_7PaddingISB_SB_EEPNS0_5PReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_7SoftmaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_14SpatialDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_21TransposedConvolutionIST_ST_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_10WeightNormISB_SB_JEEENS7_IPNS0_8Linear3DISB_SB_S32_EEJPNS0_7GlimpseISB_SB_EEPNS0_7HighwayISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18MultiheadAttentionISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_9RecurrentISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18RecurrentAttentionISB_SB_EEPNS0_15ReinforceNormalISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ReparametrizationISB_SB_EEPNS0_6SelectISB_SB_EEPNS0_10SequentialISB_SB_Lb0EJEEEPNS59_ISB_SB_Lb1EJEEEPNS0_7SubviewISB_SB_EEPNS0_13VRClassRewardISB_SB_EEPNS0_16VirtualBatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_3RBFISB_SB_NS0_16GaussianFunctionEEEPNSY_IS5O_SB_SB_EEPNS0_18PositionalEncodingISB_SB_EEEEEEEESaIS5X_EERNSA_IT_EEm]+0x248): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann21NetworkInitializationINS0_20RandomInitializationEJEE10InitializeIdEEvRKSt6vectorIN5boost7variantIPNS0_18AdaptiveMaxPoolingIN4arma3MatIdEESB_EEJPNS0_19AdaptiveMeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_3AddISB_SB_EEPNS0_8AddMergeISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_12AlphaDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_17AtrousConvolutionINS0_16NaiveConvolutionINS0_16ValidConvolutionEEENSR_INS0_15FullConvolutionEEEST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_9BaseLayerINS0_16LogisticFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16IdentityFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_12TanhFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16SoftplusFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_17RectifierFunctionESB_SB_EEPNS0_9BatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_21BilinearInterpolationISB_SB_EEPNS0_4CELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6ConcatISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_11ConcatenateISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ConcatPerformanceINS0_21NegativeLogLikelihoodISB_SB_EESB_SB_EEPNS0_8ConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_11ConvolutionIST_SV_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_5CReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_11DropConnectISB_SB_EEPNS0_7DropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_3ELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8FastLSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_12FlexibleReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_3GRUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8HardTanHISB_SB_EEPNS0_4JoinISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LayerNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LeakyReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LinearISB_SB_NS0_13NoRegularizerEEEPNS0_12LinearNoBiasISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_10LogSoftMaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LookupISB_SB_EEPNS0_4LSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_10MaxPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_11MeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_23MiniBatchDiscriminationISB_SB_EEPNS0_16MultiplyConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_13MultiplyMergeISB_SB_JEEEPS1V_PNS0_11NoisyLinearISB_SB_EEPNS0_7PaddingISB_SB_EEPNS0_5PReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_7SoftmaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_14SpatialDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_21TransposedConvolutionIST_ST_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_10WeightNormISB_SB_JEEENS7_IPNS0_8Linear3DISB_SB_S32_EEJPNS0_7GlimpseISB_SB_EEPNS0_7HighwayISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18MultiheadAttentionISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_9RecurrentISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18RecurrentAttentionISB_SB_EEPNS0_15ReinforceNormalISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ReparametrizationISB_SB_EEPNS0_6SelectISB_SB_EEPNS0_10SequentialISB_SB_Lb0EJEEEPNS59_ISB_SB_Lb1EJEEEPNS0_7SubviewISB_SB_EEPNS0_13VRClassRewardISB_SB_EEPNS0_16VirtualBatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_3RBFISB_SB_NS0_16GaussianFunctionEEEPNSY_IS5O_SB_SB_EEPNS0_18PositionalEncodingISB_SB_EEEEEEEESaIS5X_EERNSA_IT_EEm[_ZN6mlpack3ann21NetworkInitializationINS0_20RandomInitializationEJEE10InitializeIdEEvRKSt6vectorIN5boost7variantIPNS0_18AdaptiveMaxPoolingIN4arma3MatIdEESB_EEJPNS0_19AdaptiveMeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_3AddISB_SB_EEPNS0_8AddMergeISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_12AlphaDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_17AtrousConvolutionINS0_16NaiveConvolutionINS0_16ValidConvolutionEEENSR_INS0_15FullConvolutionEEEST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_9BaseLayerINS0_16LogisticFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16IdentityFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_12TanhFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_16SoftplusFunctionESB_SB_EEPNSY_INS0_17RectifierFunctionESB_SB_EEPNS0_9BatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_21BilinearInterpolationISB_SB_EEPNS0_4CELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6ConcatISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_11ConcatenateISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ConcatPerformanceINS0_21NegativeLogLikelihoodISB_SB_EESB_SB_EEPNS0_8ConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_11ConvolutionIST_SV_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_5CReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_11DropConnectISB_SB_EEPNS0_7DropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_3ELUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8FastLSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_12FlexibleReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_3GRUISB_SB_EEPNS0_8HardTanHISB_SB_EEPNS0_4JoinISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LayerNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_9LeakyReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LinearISB_SB_NS0_13NoRegularizerEEEPNS0_12LinearNoBiasISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_10LogSoftMaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_6LookupISB_SB_EEPNS0_4LSTMISB_SB_EEPNS0_10MaxPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_11MeanPoolingISB_SB_EEPNS0_23MiniBatchDiscriminationISB_SB_EEPNS0_16MultiplyConstantISB_SB_EEPNS0_13MultiplyMergeISB_SB_JEEEPS1V_PNS0_11NoisyLinearISB_SB_EEPNS0_7PaddingISB_SB_EEPNS0_5PReLUISB_SB_EEPNS0_7SoftmaxISB_SB_EEPNS0_14SpatialDropoutISB_SB_EEPNS0_21TransposedConvolutionIST_ST_ST_SB_SB_EEPNS0_10WeightNormISB_SB_JEEENS7_IPNS0_8Linear3DISB_SB_S32_EEJPNS0_7GlimpseISB_SB_EEPNS0_7HighwayISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18MultiheadAttentionISB_SB_S32_EEPNS0_9RecurrentISB_SB_JEEEPNS0_18RecurrentAttentionISB_SB_EEPNS0_15ReinforceNormalISB_SB_EEPNS0_17ReparametrizationISB_SB_EEPNS0_6SelectISB_SB_EEPNS0_10SequentialISB_SB_Lb0EJEEEPNS59_ISB_SB_Lb1EJEEEPNS0_7SubviewISB_SB_EEPNS0_13VRClassRewardISB_SB_EEPNS0_16VirtualBatchNormISB_SB_EEPNS0_3RBFISB_SB_NS0_16GaussianFunctionEEEPNSY_IS5O_SB_SB_EEPNS0_18PositionalEncodingISB_SB_EEEEEEEESaIS5X_EERNSA_IT_EEm]+0x24f): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNWv7em.o: in function `void mlpack::ann::Dropout<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >::Forward<double>(arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double>&)':
minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann7DropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann7DropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0xd7): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann7DropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann7DropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0xe7): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNWv7em.o: in function `void mlpack::ann::SpatialDropout<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >::Forward<double>(arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double>&)':
minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann14SpatialDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann14SpatialDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0x386): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann14SpatialDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann14SpatialDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0x38d): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNWv7em.o: in function `void mlpack::ann::AlphaDropout<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >::Forward<double>(arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double>&)':
minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann12AlphaDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann12AlphaDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0xf4): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann12AlphaDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann12AlphaDropoutIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0x104): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNWv7em.o: in function `void mlpack::ann::DropConnect<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >::Forward<double>(arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double>&)':
minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann11DropConnectIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann11DropConnectIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0x16c): undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance'
/usr/bin/ld: minimumReproducableCodeForMLError.cpp:(.text._ZN6mlpack3ann11DropConnectIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_[_ZN6mlpack3ann11DropConnectIN4arma3MatIdEES4_E7ForwardIdEEvRKNS3_IT_EERS8_]+0x17c): undefined reference to `arma::mt19937_64_instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

### Edit 1:

As per request in comments below, I tried running `nm` tool on my output file, armadillo, and mlpack and this is the output.

So, I tired it on armadillo and mlpack
I got some values
I did nm --demangle libarmadillo.so.10.7.4 | grep arma::mt and I got

```
00000000000008 B arma::mt19937_64_instance
00000000000cdd0 T TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance
```

and for libmlpack.so.3.4 I got

```
             U arma::mat19937_64_instance
000000199730 W void arma::op_stddev::apply<arma::Mat..........................> //This line doesn't have mat19937_64
             U TLS init function for arma::mt19937_64_instance
```

Comment: Are you able to `nm` and demangle the object files/libs, so you can see if the `arma::mt19937_64_instance` is actually where it belongs? Also - just for the sake of trying - can you check with clang instead of gcc? I'm far from blaming anything or anyone, but simple googling around suggests old GCCs had bugs related to thread local storage, maybe something got regressed?

Comment: What is `nm`? I'll try clang and let you know.

Comment: If I'm using clang, I should probably recompile everything, right?

Comment: I don't know how you compiled it, but not necessarily, I even dare say: probably not. As for nm, I meant [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) tool.

Comment: @alagner I tried `nm .\a.out | grep mt19937` and got no output.

Comment: try adding `--demangle` to nm's invocation first. Second, try invoking that on libraries, not only compiled output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239765/discussion-between-tarun-maganti-and-alagner).